# Pandas equivalent of delete from dataframe where in (...)

Tags: pandas, delete-row, where-in

I have a dataframe with an email column.
I'm trying delete all records from this dataframe where the email address exists in a second dataframe.

In SQL this would be

delete from df1 where email in (select email from df2)

Thanks

Comment: Are the dataframes indexed identically? Or do they share a unique identifier? We'll probably end up using the `pd.drop()` command, but it depends on how the two are related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `~isin`

```
In [30]: df1
Out[30]: 
   pid
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4

In [31]: df2
Out[31]: 
   pid
0    1
1    2

In [32]: df1=df1[~df1['pid'].isin(df2['pid'])]

In [33]: df1
Out[33]: 
   pid
2    3
3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do following using `where`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'email':['abc@mail.com','fgh@mail.com','cde@mail.com']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'email':['abc@mail.com']})

print(df1)
```

Output for `df1`:

```
          email
0  abc@mail.com
1  fgh@mail.com
2  cde@mail.com
```

Output for `print(df2)`:

```
     email
 0  abc@mail.com
```

Now, using `where`:

```
df1 = df1.where(~df1.email.isin(df2.email)).dropna()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
          email
1  fgh@mail.com
2  cde@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` with `drop` too.  Using boolean indexing and `.index` will drop those records form the df1 dataframe.  *Borrowing open-source's setup*

```
df1 = df1.drop(df1[df1.email.isin(df2.email)].index)
```

Output:

```
          email
1  fgh@mail.com
2  cde@mail.com
```